# Regex token xboxmusic api

Tags: regex, xbox-music

I need to figure out where the error is in this regular expression with this pattern:

```
.*\"access_token\":\"(?<;token>,.*?)\".*
```

In the string where the search is made is

```
{"token_type":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/11/swt-token-profile-1.0","access_token":"http%3a%2f%2fschemas.xmlsoap.org%2fws%2f2005%2f05%2fidentity%2fclaims%2fnameidentifier=xboxmusiceidos&http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2faccesscontrolservice%2f2010%2f07%2fclaims%2fidentityprovider=https%3a%2f%2fdatamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&Audience=http%3a%2f%2fmusic.xboxlive.com&ExpiresOn=1414161447&Issuer=https%3a%2f%2fdatamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&HMACSHA256=RQYlusDkweAgvUNFK6%2fxWOY9S1IV5SOk8deMoLOvrzs%3d","expires_in":"599","scope":"http://music.xboxlive.com"}
```

The result should be the whole string after the keyword `access_token` to `expires_in` excluded:

```
http%3a%2f%2fschemas.xmlsoap.org%2fws%2f2005%2f05%2fidentity%2fclaims%2fnameidentifier=xboxmusiceidos&http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2faccesscontrolservice%2f2010%2f07%2fclaims%2fidentityprovider=https%3a%2f%2fdatamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&Audience=http%3a%2f%2fmusic.xboxlive.com&ExpiresOn=1414161447&Issuer=https%3a%2f%2fdatamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&HMACSHA256=RQYlusDkweAgvUNFK6%2fxWOY9S1IV5SOk8deMoLOvrzs%3d
```

Comment: That looks like JSON, and if it is you should use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression:
`(?<=access\_token\"\:\").*(?=\"\,\"expires_in)`

Your Lookahead and Lookbehind operators were not correct.